# BETWEEN in SQL Throwing error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, case, between

I am trying to execute below query:

```
Declare @Range varchar(20) = '2'
SELECT mydate from  tbl_details
where 
CASE WHEN @Range = '1' THEN mydate between convert(Datetime, '12/07/2013') and convert(Datetime, '12/07/2014')
ELSE
DATEDIFF(DD, CONVERT(Datetime, mydate), GETDATE()) <= 
DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), (GETDATE()+ CONVERT(Integer, @Range))) END
```

But it is throwing error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'
```

If i give there queries individually, they work fine, as in:

```
Declare @Range varchar(20) = '2'
    SELECT mydate from  tbl_details
    where DATEDIFF(DD, CONVERT(Datetime, mydate), GETDATE()) <= 
    DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), (GETDATE()+ CONVERT(Integer, @Range)))
```

or

```
Declare @Range varchar(20) = '2'
    SELECT mydate from  tbl_details
    where 
    mydate between convert(Datetime, '12/07/2013') and convert(Datetime, '12/07/2014')
```

Comment: Joe's answer is more then sufficient so I won't post this as an answer but basically what you got wrong is the case syntax (like the error said). Case works like this: case when (condition) then (result) else (other result) end. You put a condition in the place where should be the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax doesn't work in SQL. One way to adjust it would be to break out the range into two sides of an `OR`:

```
where 
    (
        @Range = '1'
        and
        mydate between convert(Datetime, '12/07/2013') and convert(Datetime, '12/07/2014')
    )
    or
    (
        @Range <> '1'
        and
        DATEDIFF(DD, CONVERT(Datetime, mydate), GETDATE()) 
        <= 
        DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), (GETDATE()+ CONVERT(Integer, @Range)))
    )
```